# Problema Angular - Spring conexión

Tags: html, angular, spring-boot

estoy tratando de unir Angular con Spring Boot pero tengo problemas y no me esta cargando mi data de mi base de datos en mi html, me esta lanzando este error en mi front-end , estoy utilizando CORS ; implemente el servicio listarUsuario en la parte Spring y lo quiero mostrar en una tabla ;¿Qué error estoy cometiendo?. Gracias por su ayuda se los agradeceria.

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:3193)
    at callHook (core.js:3285)
    at callHooks (core.js:3251)
    at executeCheckHooks (core.js:3184)
    at refreshView (core.js:7335)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:8473)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:7132)
    at refreshView (core.js:7376)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:8427)
    at refreshView (core.js:7350)
```

este es el código en spring , está la ruta de Angular y las ruta principal que es el RequestMapping y la ruta de listar

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:4200"})
@RequestMapping("/api/usu")
public class UsuarioRestControlador {
    
    @Autowired
    private UsuarioServicio usuarioServicio;
    
    @GetMapping("/listarUsuario")
    public Map<String,Object> listarUsuario(){
        Map<String,Object> rpta= new HashMap<String,Object>();
        List<Usuario> listaUsuario = usuarioServicio.listarUsuario();
        rpta.put("listado",listaUsuario);
        return rpta;
    }
```

este es el código en angular:
este es el servicio, esta la ruta de mi localhost , tambien estoy importando mi clase Usuario

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {USUARIO} from '../usuario/usuario.json';
import {Usuario} from './usuario'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {of} from 'rxjs';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class UsuarioService{
    
    private url : string = 'http://localhost:8080/api/usu/listarUsuario';

    constructor(private http:HttpClient){
    }

    getUsuarios():Observable<Usuario[]>{

        return this.http.get<Usuario[]>(this.url);
    }
}
```

este es el Json que devuelve en el Spring

```
{"listado":[{"fec_REG_USUARIO":"2020-10-22T11:38:14.383","contra_USUARIO":"1234","usu_USUARIO":"local2","nom_USUARIO":"carlos aldair","fec_NAC":null,"id_USUARIO":2,"apell_USUARIO":"zavala"},{"fec_REG_USUARIO":"2020-10-26T13:52:35.253","contra_USUARIO":"1234","usu_USUARIO":"local2","nom_USUARIO":"juan","fec_NAC":null,"id_USUARIO":3,"apell_USUARIO":"zavala tomayro"},{"fec_REG_USUARIO":"2020-10-26T13:53:20.477","contra_USUARIO":"123","usu_USUARIO":"local2","nom_USUARIO":"matias","fec_NAC":null,"id_USUARIO":4,"apell_USUARIO":"tomayro"},{"fec_REG_USUARIO":"2020-10-26T15:27:07.103","contra_USUARIO":"123","usu_USUARIO":"local2","nom_USUARIO":"carlos","fec_NAC":null,"id_USUARIO":5,"apell_USUARIO":"tomayro"},{"fec_REG_USUARIO":"2020-10-26T15:57:55.697","contra_USUARIO":"contrasena","usu_USUARIO":"usuario","nom_USUARIO":"nombre","fec_NAC":null,"id_USUARIO":6,"apell_USUARIO":"apellido"},{"fec_REG_USUARIO":"2020-10-26T16:04:21.93","contra_USUARIO":"123","usu_USUARIO":"123","nom_USUARIO":"mati","fec_NAC":null,"id_USUARIO":7,"apell_USUARIO":"casas"},{"fec_REG_USUARIO":"2020-10-26T16:05:36.33","contra_USUARIO":"123","usu_USUARIO":"123","nom_USUARIO":"cristian","fec_NAC":null,"id_USUARIO":8,"apell_USUARIO":"quispe"},{"fec_REG_USUARIO":"2020-10-26T16:06:35.517","contra_USUARIO":"123","usu_USUARIO":"123","nom_USUARIO":"manolo","fec_NAC":null,"id_USUARIO":9,"apell_USUARIO":"cazt"},{"fec_REG_USUARIO":"2020-10-27T11:34:56.797","contra_USUARIO":"1234","usu_USUARIO":"1234","nom_USUARIO":"juan carlos","fec_NAC":null,"id_USUARIO":12,"apell_USUARIO":"carballo"},{"fec_REG_USUARIO":"2020-10-27T16:49:44.233","contra_USUARIO":"8778","usu_USUARIO":"54+","nom_USUARIO":"guty","fec_NAC":null,"id_USUARIO":13,"apell_USUARIO":"quispe arias"},{"fec_REG_USUARIO":"2020-10-30T19:08:53.773","contra_USUARIO":"48878","usu_USUARIO":"yayito","nom_USUARIO":"yayito lucas","fec_NAC":"2017-06-13T05:00:00.000+00:00","id_USUARIO":15,"apell_USUARIO":"husto"},{"fec_REG_USUARIO":"2020-11-10T16:19:01.49","contra_USUARIO":"1234","usu_USUARIO":"local2","nom_USUARIO":"aldair","fec_NAC":"0024-12-15T05:00:00.000+00:00","id_USUARIO":16,"apell_USUARIO":"zavala"},{"fec_REG_USUARIO":"2020-11-10T16:19:45.577","contra_USUARIO":"1234","usu_USUARIO":"local2","nom_USUARIO":"aldair","fec_NAC":"0024-12-15T05:00:00.000+00:00","id_USUARIO":17,"apell_USUARIO":"zavala"},{"fec_REG_USUARIO":"2020-11-10T16:20:02.04","contra_USUARIO":"1234","usu_USUARIO":"local2","nom_USUARIO":"pepito","fec_NAC":"0024-12-15T05:00:00.000+00:00","id_USUARIO":18,"apell_USUARIO":"casas"},{"fec_REG_USUARIO":"2020-11-10T16:20:51.72","contra_USUARIO":"1234","usu_USUARIO":"local2","nom_USUARIO":"patito","fec_NAC":"1995-07-19T05:00:00.000+00:00","id_USUARIO":19,"apell_USUARIO":"casas"}]}
```

aquí recibo el servicio

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Usuario} from '../usuario/usuario';
import {UsuarioService} from '../usuario/usuario.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-listar',
  templateUrl: './listar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listar.component.css']
})
export class ListarComponent implements OnInit {

  usuarios:Usuario[];

  constructor(private usuarioService:UsuarioService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.usuarioService.getUsuarios().subscribe(

       usuarios =>this.usuarios = usuarios

    );
  }

}
```

este es el html

```
<div class="container">

    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped contenedor">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>nombre</th>
                <th>apellido</th>
                <th>usuario</th>
                <th>contaseña</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios">
                <td>{{usuario.nombre}}</td>
                <td>{{usuario.apellido}}</td>
                <td>{{usuario.usuario}}</td>
                <td>{{usuario.contra}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La lista de usuarios que retorna el backend está en una propiedad llamada `listado`:

```
 rpta.put("listado",listaUsuario);
```

En el servicio de Angular se tiene que acceder a esa propiedad:

```
 usuarios =>this.usuarios = usuarios.listado
```

**Actualización**

```
( usuarios : any ) => this.usuarios = usuarios.listado
```

Comment: tambien me da error de sintaxis

Comment: Agrega en tu pregunta el json que devuelve el backend para revisarlo.

Comment: ya esta , ya lo agregué

Comment: Eso es la consulta que hace hibernate para listar los usuarios. Escribe la url de la API en el navegador para que te imprima ahí el json.

Comment: ahora si , disculpa entendí mal

Comment: Ok , actualicé la respuesta. El error de sintaxis es porque` Clientes[]` no tiene una propiedad llamada `listado`, haciendo `usuarios` de tipo any debe funcionar.

Comment: me muestra la tabla vacía amigo

Comment: Ahora revisa el mapeo de las propiedades porque en la tabla se usa `usuario.nombre` pero en el arreglo es `nom_USUARIO`. La clase Usuario debe tener propiedades con el mismo nombre que las que están en el json.